# cannot import mysql database using sqoop

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I created a database using mysql named 'dz' and have two tables in it. Then i tried to import the tables using apache sqoop. I am getting the following error.

```
Warning: /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/11/30 15:47:40 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/11/30 15:47:40 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/11/30 15:47:40 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/11/30 15:47:40 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/11/30 15:47:40 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sqoop_import` AS t LIMIT 1
17/11/30 15:47:40 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Base table or view not found message from server: "Table 'dz.sqoop_import' doesn't exist"
java.sql.SQLException: Base table or view not found message from server: "Table 'dz.sqoop_import' doesn't exist"
....
```

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: The message is clear: `Table 'dz.sqoop_import' doesn't exist`. Are you sure the settings to connect to the database are ok? user/password/database name? Are the tables created?

Comment: yes. I created the database dz using mysql terminal. Then i created two tables in it. Is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: Edit your answer, please, and add Sqoop command you try to execute.

Comment: There was a typo in the command so i fixed it myself. Thanks @Mateusz Grabowski

Comment: Please paste the command sqoop here that is being used and verify in mysql whether the table exists or not..